# How can I conditionally render different components on initial load in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I have the code below, and it all works.

Now, I would like to add a new component which will render a different navbar and have different routing.

How can I conditionally render the different components on initial load?

Option:
Split the current App.js code into two different components, and each component will have their own navbar and routing.

This option would be the most ideal, but I would like to render only one component first and if the user visits the different section of the site, load the other component.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from '../Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from '../../Pages/Home/Home';
import Services from '../../Pages/Services/Services';
import Bicultural from '../../Pages/Bicultural/Bicultural';
import Training from '../../Pages/Training/Training';
import Talent from '../../Pages/Talent/Talent';
import Mission from '../../Pages/Mission/Mission';
import Team from '../../Pages/Team/Team';
import About from '../../Pages/About/About';
import Blog from '../../Pages/Blog/Blog';
import Careers from '../../Pages/Careers/Careers';
import Contact from '../../Pages/Contact/Contact';
import NoMatch from '../../Pages/NoMatch/NoMatch';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';
import ScrollToTop from '../ScrollUpButton/ScrollToTop';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Navigation className="no-bg" />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/services" component={Services} />
            <Route exact path="/bicultural" component={Bicultural} />
            <Route exact path="/training" component={Training} />
            <Route exact path="/talent" component={Talent} />
            <Route exact path="/mission" component={Mission} />
            <Route exact path="/team" component={Team} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/blog" component={Blog} />
            <Route exact path="/careers" component={Careers} />
            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
        <ScrollToTop />
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>


  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple state variable called showNav and pass its setState function inside each of your Route as a prop. Then your component could set that prop to true or false depending on whether you want to display your nav on that route or not.

```
const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true);
{showNav && <Navigation className="no-bg"/> }
```

pass it inside your routes like this :-

```
<Route exact path="/" render ={(props) = > 
    <Home {...props} setShowNav={setShowNav}/>}
/>
```

And then inside the prop, just before returning the component you could do this to not show the nav

```
props.setShowNav(false);
```

Although, make sure you pass the setShowNav function inside each of your components and those components call setShowNav(true), in case you want to display your nav